# Run shell script from windows batch file

Tags: windows, unix, batch-processing

I have below requirement
I am copying files from windows to unix server and then to hadoop server
once i run my batch file and files copy are completed, i want to execute shell script in unix server from windows batch file itself and once files are copied from unix to hadoop, i want to create touch files in windows to indicate one set of files are copied from windows to unix , so that i can ignore them copying again. Can any one please suggest how to accomplish this , i am new to parallel processing of copying data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy files to unix server (seems you have this solved)
2. Use plink program from putty package to start command in unix
   server. Needed is a ssh daemon running in unix server. Output of
   command in remote server can be obtained and readed to know file
   copy has ended.
3. Generate the touch files. `break > filename` is sufficient to
   generate a file with 0 bytes.

Comment: Hi , i am not able start SSH demon in unix server. i login into unix using putty, and i run the command /sbin/service sshd start, but it saying ksh:/sbin/service: not found,  I dont see service under sbin folder, do I need to install anything, to start ssh daemon ,Please suggest

Comment: sorry if its a dumb question, i am not finding proper information on plink, I have putty installed , do we need to run the plink program as a command from command prompt , can i use plink in same batch files which i am using it for copying files to unix server, can you provide pointers for syntax

Comment: From [putty download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) you can get the program (if not yet in your installation). From this same site, you can get the documentation of each of the programs, including [plink documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink)